# Simulating groups different with respect to the orthogonal complement in R

Tags: distributions, correlation, pca, group-differences

In a paper of Journal of Chemometrics (Naes & Mevik 2001 : Understanding the collinearity problem in regression and discriminant analysis), the authors propose to make simulations by creating two groups which are different with respect to the smallest eigenvector direction.

> Here the groups are different with respect to the orthogonal complement to the ﬁve ‘NIR loadings’. This is achieved in the following way. The constant 0 ⋅ 18 is multiplied by a sixth loading vector (orthogonal to the other ﬁve) and added to group 2. Both groups had initially the same means as group 1

How can I compute such a simulation in R? The goal is to obtain group differences which are tied to the "small eigenvectors" space. Then to check whether the LDA results are best when using the whole dataset or better by using only the last components as variables.

---

**Edit**
I am trying to get the same results as these authors by simulation, but unfortunately...

I have tried to make two groups in a set of correlated data by adding differences between groups in the last eigen-vector (as it was suggested to me):

Here is a try:

```
require(MASS)
R=matrix(0.9,10,10);
diag(R)=1;
random.normal=mvrnorm(n=20, rep(1,10), Sigma=R) ;
V <- var(random.normal) ## vcv matrix
U <- eigen(V)$vectors ## eigen vectors
Y <- random.normal %*% U
group=rep(1:2,each=10)
Y10 <- Y[,10] ## temporary data
Y10[group==1] <- Y10[group==1]+1 ## add 1 to group 1
Y10 <- Y10*sqrt(var(Y[,10])/var(Y10)) ## scaling to the variance of Y[,10]
Y[,10] <- Y10-mean(Y10)+mean(Y[,10]) ## center

X2 <- Y %*% t(U) #data back transformed

## Then I try LDA with MASS

test=lda(X2,group,CV=T)
tab=table(test$class,group)
sum(diag(tab))/sum(tab)
```

But unfortunately I never found the bad classification results that Naes & Mevik 2001 found. when I use the complete dataset instead of using the last PC in the LDA as these authors found. (it's the same with more variables)
I found that results are even better with the firsts components (e.g. 1:5 for ten PC)

```
test=lda(prcomp(X2)$x[,1:5],group,CV=T)
    tab=table(test$class,group)
sum(diag(tab))/sum(tab)
```

Any suggestions to found the effects these authors explain?
Thank a lot

Comment: Julien, please visit our [Help Center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your two unregistered accounts.